# A harmonic function on an annulus

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I have been working on the following problem for quite seem to figure out the end. So far, I have proven that for a real valued harmonic function $u$ on the annulus $A=\big\{z:\rho<|z|<R\big\}$, there exists bi-infinite sequences of real numbers $\big\{a_n,b_n\big\}$ so that if $z = re^{i\theta}$, then we have a locally uniformly convergent expansion:
$$u(z) = a_0+b_0\log r +\sum_{n=1}^\infty [(a_nr^n+a_{-n}r^{-n})\cos n \theta +(b_nr^n +b_{-n}r^{-n})\sin n\theta ]$$
The last part of the exercise asks to give a condition, in terms of this expansion, for $u$ to have a single valued harmonic conjugate in $A$. Is there something trivial that I am missing here? Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $b_0=0$ is the necessary and sufficient condition (the conjugate of $\log |z|$ is $\arg z$ and there is no way to make that well defined in a continuous way on the full annulus, while it is very easy to write the coefficients of the conjugate in terms of $a_n, a_{-n}, b_n, b_{-n}, n \ge 1$)

Comment: Would you mind showing how you write the coefficients of the conjugate in terms of $a_n$, $a_{-n}$, $b_n$ and $b_{-n}$ for $n \geq 1$? I have been working on this for a while and can't figure it out.

Comment: Write $r^n\cos n\theta$ etc in terms of $z^n, \bar z^n$ (here $n$ positive or negative and nonzero) and then the conjugate is precisely the expression $v$ st $u+iv$ has no conjugate terms (the coefficients of $\bar z^n$ are zero for all integral $n \ne 0$); this should give them term by term (something like $c_n=\pm ib_n, d_n= \pm ia_n$ where $v$ has $c_n$ the cosine coefficients etc (in other words the coefficients switch and get multiplied by $\pm i$) at least more or less (just identify them term by term using the above and the fact that $a_n$ etc are real)

Comment: I see. Thank you!